# Rename documents in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array with documents paths, is there any way to go through the array and to rename each file on the disk using JavaScript?

For example:

```
var arr=["../images/1.pdf","../images/2.pdf","../images/3.pdf"];
```

Desired output:

```
var arr=["../images/a.pdf","../images/b.pdf","../images/c.pdf"];
```

Comment: Indeed there is a way. What did you try?

Comment: @FanyoSILIADIN, not sure what you mean, I simply don't know if it's possible or not.

Comment: What do you mean by _"rename each file on the disk"_

Comment: Is this JS in the browser? Support for this isn't great if so as it's considered a security risk.

Comment: @j08691, actually changing the name of each file.

Comment: This is not possible with native JavaScript. You'll need an OS component that has security permissions to do this. On Windows systems, you can use the Windows Scripting Host or with an ActiveX Object, you can use the File System Object.

Comment: You can't do it with javascript, you will need serverside script for this. Typically you would make AJAX request and server script would do such renaming.

Comment: I believe the best JS can do now is read files, not write.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, this is what I wanted to know, if possible or not, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you'r using Javascript or not, however it *does* matter if you'r running in a browser or not.

You can't just access files on the disk from a Browser, but this is [totally possible for example from `node.js`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) or an electron application, and maybe for a browser addon and other VMs.